# How to use swipe (pull) to refresh with Material 3?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

```
val pullRefreshState = rememberPullRefreshState(loadStatus is LoadState.Loading, onRefresh = {
    photosResponse.refresh()
})
Box(
    modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .pullRefresh(pullRefreshState)
```

[image]

I have updated Material 2 to Material 3:

```
api(libs.androidx.compose.material3) // group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3"
```

But now I can't use swipe to refresh, there is nothing to import

Comment: You can use material2 functions alongside material3

Comment: @levi yeah for I did like this for now, but Ideally apps should not add the whole material2 library just for pull refresh feature :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Official version of Pull-to-refresh have been released for beta testing.
Make sure you have Material3 `1.2.0-beta01` or higher.

`implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-beta01")`

then check out example [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/pulltorefresh/package-summary). I will paste example for future reference if things changes in Android documentation:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.material3.ListItem
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.pulltorefresh.PullToRefreshContainer
import androidx.compose.material3.pulltorefresh.rememberPullToRefreshState
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.nestedScroll

var itemCount by remember { mutableStateOf(15) }
val state = rememberPullToRefreshState()
if (state.isRefreshing) {
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        // fetch something
        delay(1500)
        itemCount += 5
        state.endRefresh()
    }
}
Box(Modifier.nestedScroll(state.nestedScrollConnection)) {
    LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        if (!state.isRefreshing) {
            items(itemCount) {
                ListItem({ Text(text = "Item ${itemCount - it}") })
            }
        }
    }
    PullToRefreshContainer(
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter),
        state = state,
    )
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Wow, thanks for the update

Comment: Any idea to get this working with a webview?

Comment: Unfortunately this is exclusive solution for LazyColumn. You will have to figure out how to work with Webview or ask as separate question that someone knowledgable can help!

Answer (score -2):

You might need to implement this

```
implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-swiperefresh:0.28.0'
```

Comment: no, this one deprecated

Comment: @user924 you might be wait until mid of this year. 
Please check this tracker was response by google team.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/261760718

Comment: for lib with M3 https://github.com/Omico/androidx-compose-material3-pullrefresh